# How to redirect all routes to index page in web config on azure?

Tags: reactjs, azure, url-rewriting, web-config, react-router

I am working with a react application deployed on azure. I am using react routers Browserhistory module. Currently I have the following rule in my web.config on azure:

```
<rule name="admin rule" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="admin" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" matchType="Pattern" pattern="api/(.*)" negate="true" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Rewrite" url="/" />
</rule>
```

And this works, the /admin route can be refreshed and manually entered in the browsers URL window. If this rule isn't applied I can't refresh or manually enter the URL. (see issue: [React-router URLs don't work when refreshing or writing manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually))

But I actually want this to work for every route, also dynamic routes. for example:

- /cart
- /product/uniqueid
- /example

Which rule can I write so that every route is being rewritten to the index like in the admin route?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to swap your admin match rule for `<match url=".*" />` right above your opening `<conditions>` tag. Check [this blog post](https://medium.com/@to_pe/deploying-create-react-app-on-microsoft-azure-c0f6686a4321) for more information.